# Python script - log failed icmp/ping response - problems

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm attempting to write a Python script that will ping/icmp an IP address and tell me if it's alive.  I'm doing this because I have a intermittent issue.  I wanted to ping, log the outcome, sleep for a period and attempt the ping again.  I tried a while loop, but still getting errors like these:

```
line 33, in (module) systemPing('192.168.1.1')
line 30, in systemPing time.sleep(30)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I'm using Python 2.6.

Ideally my question is how I loop through this method/function systemPing and what errors there are in my code?  The script seems to work, but I get these errors when I hit ctrl-c.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import datetime, time, re 

logFile = open("textlog.txt", "a")

def getmyTime():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M \n")

startTime = "Starting ..." + getmyTime()
logFile.write(startTime)
logFile.write("\n")

def systemPing(x):
    cmd = Popen("ping -n 1 " + x , stdout=PIPE)
    #print getmyTime()
    for line in cmd.stdout:
        if 'timed out' in line:
            loggedTime = "Failure detected - " + getmyTime()
            logFile.write(loggedTime)
        if 'Reply' in line:
            print "Replied..."
    logFile.close() 
    print "Sleeping 30mins ... CTRL C to end"
    time.sleep(30) #1800 is 30mins
    systemPing('192.168.1.1')

if __name__ =='__main__':
    systemPing('192.168.1.1')
```

Any help is always appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really an error per se, it's just the default behavior for Python, upon receipt of a [`SIGINT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_%28POSIX%29#SIGINT) (which is what happens when you press CTRL-C), to raise a [`KeyboardInterrupt`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt) exception.

You'll get the same thing if you send the signal with [`kill(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill), like...

```
$ kill -INT <pid>
```

If you want to handle it, then you can change the code to something like...

```
if __name__ =='__main__':
    try:
        systemPing('192.168.1.1')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'Finished'
```

...or whatever you want it to do.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  I was wondering why it seemed to work but yet I'm getting what I perceived as errors.  I hadn't thought of that approach, but haven't ever used it. I will edit the script and test. Thank you.

Comment: That try/except statement doesn't loop.  It just runs once and exits.  On a positive note; without any errors.

Comment: @user2105764 It's not supposed to loop. I thought you just wanted to allow CTRL-C to exit the program without an error message. Do you actually want to disable CTRL-C?

Comment: I wanted it to loop through the systemPing function. I nested the try/except statement in a while True loop and seems ok, but will need to test longer